# Submit the same form with three buttons using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having a problem to submit the same form three times, but with different actions. Please see the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){
     // Some code here
}
if(isset($_POST['btn_sub'])){
    // Some other code here
}
```

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <!-- Some input fields -->
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <!-- Some more input fields -->
        <input type="submit" name="btn_sub" id="btn_sub" value="Submit" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Now when I clicked on the first submit button,  I got the posted values in the *POST* array (with button name i.e., `$_POST['btn_submit']=> Submit`), but when I clicked on the second button then also I got all posted values in the *POST* array except the name of the button (i.e., `$_POST['btn_sub'] => Submit`).

On the second button click I want to update some database records, but because of its condition `if(isset($_POST['btn_sub']))` is not true, so it's not entering into this condition and my database records are not updated. The rest of the array elements shows, but not the submit button.

This functionality is working on my local server, but after uploading it on a live server it's not working.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: change different value Submit1 and Submit2

Comment: @Devyesh, thanks for instant reply, I tried it as well first button value as 'Submit' and second as 'Save', but my problem is not solved.
When first button is clicked then before second button one div shown with some records(with hidden and shown text boxes) and when second button clicked then hidden values are posted (shown in POST array) but button name not shown any idea why this is so ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table>
      <tr>
          <!-- Some input fields -->
          <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit2" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <!-- Some more input fields -->
          <input type="submit" name="btn_sub" id="btn_sub" value="Submit1" />
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Answers are better when there is more details than `Try this code`. Why should the OP try your code? What did you change in the code block?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34960615/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Use the same name for the submit button:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <!-- Common input fields -->
      <input type="text" name="commontxt" id="commontxt" value="common text field" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Some input fields -->
      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit1" value="Submit 1" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- Some more input fields -->
      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit2" value="Submit 2" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Check which submit button is clicked in this way:

```
if (!empty( $_POST))
{
  if ($_POST['btn_submit'] == 'Submit 1') {
    // Action for Submit 1 here
    $commontxt = $_POST['commontxt'];
    echo 'Submit 1<br/>';
    echo $commontxt;
  } else if ($_POST['btn_submit'] == 'Submit 2') {
    // Action for Submit 2 here
    $commontxt = $_POST['commontxt'];
    echo 'Submit 2<br/>';
    echo $commontxt;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call a submit button an "input field"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches you can follow here:

**Approach 1:**

If you can change the page on submit, meaning on click of the submit button, the request goes to two different pages. There is a new HTML5 approach to handle this:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/action_one">SUBMIT</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="/action_two">SUBMIT</button>
```

Apparently this does not work in [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) and earlier, but for other browsers you should be fine (see: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp), the HTML <button> *formaction* attribute).

**Approach 2**

JavaScript Method:

```
<input type="submit" value="dosomething" onclick="javascript:
form.action='actionurl1';"/>
<input type="submit" value="dosomethingelse" onclick="javascript:
form.action='actionurl2';"/>
```

**Approach 3**

If you want to keep the same page on submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="row[1]" value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name="row[2]" value="Submit">
```

And then in the server side (PHP in my example) you can read "row" as an array to get the index:

```
$index = key($_POST['row']);
```

$_POST['row'] will be an array with just one element, in the form index => value (for example: '2' => 'something").

[Read Here About Index Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

### New answer as per the OP's approach

I have tried your *form structure* and I am getting the second button name perfectly.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']) && empty($_POST['btn_sub']) ){
     echo "First Submit-----------<br/>";
     print_r($_POST);
}
else if(isset($_POST['btn_sub']) && empty($_POST['btn_submit'])){
    echo "Second Submit-----------<br/>";
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

?>

#### HTML

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <input type="text" value="Form1" name="form1_input" />
      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <input type="text" value="Form2" name="form2_input" />
      <input type="submit" name="btn_sub" id="btn_sub" value="Submit" />
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

> Check this out and also confirm if you are nor repeating the same name on the page...

My output on second submit:

```
Second Submit-----------
Array ([form1_input] => Form1 [form2_input] => Form2 [btn_sub] => Submit)
```

Comment: hi Gags, thanks for reply, I tried your solution of third approach but no luck. and get the error key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in file name with path on line number. This is because btn_submit doesn't get the array number. That button is on third number before it second button is empty.

Comment: Please post how you have tried? And have u read that post row will be an array with one element.

Comment: my html structure is like <form><some input fields><input button1><again some input buttons><input button2><div>for loop open<more input buttons>for loop closed</div><input button3></form>
all the submit buttons have names like btn_submit[1], btn_submit[2] & btn_submit[3] respectively. When I clicked on first button then in the condition of first button I fetch some records whose ids are in hidden firlds & two visible input fields. And after clicking last 3rd button hidden fields and visible fields values are posted but not button name.